# Drupal: Node Submission Time

Tags: drupal

How do I print into a block the node submission time.
something like... `print $node->submitted_time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$node->created` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

add block -> choose php filter, add code:

```
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if ($node) {
    print format_date($node->created);
  }
}
```